# How do I trigger execution of apk on event in android?

Tags: java, android, sms, apk, startup

I have programmed a SMS handler application in Java and I would like to start my application on start up, as well as triggered on text message broadcast received.

Does anyone have any idea how to accomplish this and where to begin my research ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

register receiver for android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED event and start your application.

Also note that as of Android 3.0 the user needs to have started the application at least once before your application can receive android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED events.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Do you know if its possible to execute the program on an event ?